# Artifacts about rendering ajacent cubes with opengl es?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was trying to render rubix cubes with opengl es on android. Here is how I do it: I render 27 ajacent cubes. And the faces of the cubes which is covered is textured with black bmp picture and other faces that can be seen is textured with colorful picture. I used cull face and depth-test to avoid rendering useless faces. But look at what I got, it is pretty wierd. The black faces show up sometimes. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the artifacts?

Screenshots:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Depth buffer precision issues would be the immediate guess — the depth buffer is only so precise so if polygons are close in range then it can inadvertently conclude that a further one is closer, but only on certain pixels. Can you post a screenshot (or a link to one; someone can move it directly into your post)? It'd save writing a long answer about that if the issue is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I do have some screenshots but it seems that I don't have enough reputation to post a picture.

Comment: Is there anywhere else you can put them? Imageshack or anywhere like that? Users with more reputation are allowed to move images inline so I could add them directly to your question — that way even if I don't know the answer, somebody else might be more likely to work it out.

Comment: I put the screenshots on imageshack. Here is the url:http://imageshack.us/g/1/10306328/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the benefit of screenshots it looks like the depth buffering simply isn't having any effect — would it be safe to conclude that you render the side of the cube with the blue faces first, then the central section behind it, then the back face?

I'm slightly out of my depth with the Android stuff but I think the confusion is probably just that enabling the depth test within OpenGL isn't sufficient. You also have to ensure that a depth buffer is allocated.

Probably you have a call to `setEGLConfigChooser` that's disabling the depth buffer. There are a bunch of overloaded variants of that method but the single boolean version and the one that allows redSize, greenSize, etc to be specified give you explicit control over whether there's a depth buffer size. So you'll want to check those.

If you're creating your framebuffer explicitly then make sure you are attaching a depth renderbuffer.

Comment: I just rendered only one cube to testify whether the depth-test is useful. And I found that you are right about the depth-buffering not having effect stuff~

Comment: I do find a setEGLConfigChooser call that disabled the depth buffer. Thank you so much for noticing me of that. I think I got the problem sovled.